# css - right vertical line displaying on iPhone 5 (on the right side)

Tags: css, iphone

My client complains that this page, http://www.lingojungle.com/, on IPhone 5 shows a white vertical line (probably 1 or 2px wide) on the right side of the page. I do not have IPhone 5, but when I try on a browser or simulator, I do not get this line.

First, I need to understand - what causes this line. Second - how to fix it.

Unfortunately, I cannot add many comments here, as I do not see this on any of my devices. I will add more comments when the problem would be clear.

Comment: Could you ask your client for a screenshot? I do not see any lines on my end other than the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is .hor-line-home-text class that has a width of 321px applied to it that is causing the issue. Remove the width setting or set it to auto.

Comment: I think I have fixed it. Thx. Maybe you can answer another question - why during scrolling on mobile phone we can see vertical grey line on right side?

Comment: Not too sure to be honest sounds like horizontal space adding on scroll? Can you get rid of bg.png on the body tag as this is white - what is this used for? If you give body a background of black does it go?

Comment: BG is used on other pages. Client asked today to remove bg from first page and I did it with jquery on first page, as all pages has the same sharedlayout. And I tried to remove bg as you mentioned, but still that line is there...